# Why does DataFrames.jl implement NA instead of using NaN?

Tags: dataframe, julia

DataFrames.jl implements `NA` for missing values:

```
help?> NA

NA

A value denoting missingness within the domain of any type.
```

Nevertheless, Julia already has a NaN type:

```
help?> NaN

NaN

A not-a-number value of type Float64.
```

What's the reason for this design decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All Programming Languages Answer:**

`NA` denotes a missing value.

`NaN` denotes an arithmetic computation that is not well defined.

By definition, they are different, thus two different "things" are needed to describe them.

For example, consider the sequence `n/n` for `n = ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...`. In this sequence, when `n = 0`, the sequence element is `0/0`, which is not well defined, and so evaluates to `NaN`. But in no way is the element of the sequence `0/0` missing, in any sense of the word, and so `NA` would be inappropriate in this situation.

The contrasting example is a sequence of observations from some environmental sensor, `a, b, NA, d`. The sensor malfunctioned for the third observation, and so it is recorded as missing. Nonetheless, there was, at the time of the third observation, some true value `c` that the sensor should have recorded had it not malfunctioned, and that is well defined arithmetically.

All you need for both "things" to occur in the same dataset is some setup where missing data can occur, as well as observations that may, under some circumstances, be arithmetically not well defined. It immediately follows that `NaN` and `NA` will need to be distinct.

**Julia Specific Answer:** `NaN` is of type `Float64`. But what if your dataset is of some other type, like `Int`, or `String`? If we use `NaN` to denote missing data, then your dataset needs to be an array of union types, eg `Union{Int, Float64}`, or `Union{String, Float64}`, which means performance will suffer (see performance tips section of official docs discussing union types). In contrast, an enormous amount of work has been done (from memory, culminating in v0.6) to ensure that `NA` can be used to represent missing data in arrays of many different types without much performance penalty. How was this achieved? This is definitely a different (but interesting) question, and one which, honestly, I think I am unqualified to answer.

Comment: Two comments to supplement the answer: 1) Julia is leaving NA - instead the new missing value is called `missing`, which explicitly denotes a missing value. A current idea is that something different, e.g. `invalid` or just the good old `nothing` should represent the result of a computation that is not defined (what's described above as NaN). `NaN`, which is explicitly `Float64` and part of the IEEE standard, will remain in the language.